# Inverse of nonsquare matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, inverse

I'm trying to solve $y = xA$ where $y = (0, 1, 0, 1)$ and

$$
A = \left(\begin{array} &
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

also everything is in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I have tried to invert it using Gauss-Jordan elimination by expanding $A$ to $7 \times 7$ matrix with this result:

$$
A^{-1} = \left(\begin{array} &
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Am I in correct path? Is there any other easier way to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: How and why did you expand the matrix $A$?

Comment: I thought that I can try to inverse it (by hand) if I expand $A$ to square matrix, inverse it, and only pick submatrix of the result.

Comment: This is unrelated to the math, but "inverse" is a noun; the verb is "invert".

Comment: Nonsquare matrices do not have inverses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want "normal" Gauss-Jordan elimination to happen, you should rewrite $y = xA$ into $A^{\mathsf T} x^{\mathsf T} = y^{\mathsf T}$, giving you $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \\ x_7\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now you can row-reduce and solve for example for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ in terms of $x_5,x_6,x_7$.

Technically you can do the same thing to the original matrix by just tilting your head and doing column reduction instead, but that's confusing to think about.